# Stuck using Stylus Studio X16 Saxon engine to text xquery

Tags: xquery, saxon

At my company, we maintain many xquery files using Stylus Studio Enterprise, currently X16 64 bit build 'o'.

For some reason, whenever we switch the processor setting from DataDirect to Saxon, our queries loop indefinitely, regardless of size.  We have to kill the struzzo.exe task.

Because of this, we have no way to debug.

The vendor has been responsive, in the sense of answering my questions, but their diagnosis is something odd in my environment.  But I have colleagues in multiple locations, who seem also to have the issue.

So my question to this community is "did you ever encounter this issue, and if so, did you resolve it?"

I am running Windows 7 - 64 bit - Java 1.8.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of an XQuery module that causes this issue? It's difficult to diagnose or hypothesize why without seeing what the XQuery module is doing.

Comment: Does it happen even with a trivial query like `2+2`?

Comment: Yes, every single query I have tried has this result.

Comment: declare function local:Add1Year($dtstr as xs:string?) as xs:string?
{
 let $dt := xs:date($dtstr) + xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y') - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
 return xs:string($dt)
};

<Test>
<Result>{local:Add1Year('2106-02-01')}</Result>
<Result>{local:Add1Year('2017-03-01')}</Result>
<Result>{local:Add1Year('2015-03-01')}</Result>
</Test>